# Find and summarise co-occurring events between timestamps by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, timestamp, grouping

I am working with a on-demand television log data set and I want to identify and summarise the number of active devices between two different timestamps. I have created a mock dataframe below; each row is a "session", and contains unique customer identifier, unique device identifier, genre of show being watched and start/end times of each session:-

```
df<-structure(list(CustomerID = c("0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", 
"0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", "0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", 
"0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", "0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", 
"0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", "0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", 
"0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", "0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", 
"0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", "0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", 
"0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", "0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", 
"0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", "0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", 
"0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", "0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87", 
"12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", "12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", 
"12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", "12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", 
"12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", "12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", 
"12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", "12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", 
"12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", "12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", 
"12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", "12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", 
"12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", "12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", 
"12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", "12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", 
"12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159", "fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", 
"fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", "fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", 
"fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", "fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", 
"fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", "fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", 
"fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", "fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", 
"fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", "fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", 
"fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", "fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", 
"fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", "fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", 
"fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", "fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88", 
"fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", "fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", 
"fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", "fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", 
"fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", "fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", 
"fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", "fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", 
"fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", "fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", 
"fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", "fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", 
"fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", "fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", 
"fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", "fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", 
"fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503", "e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", 
"e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", "e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", 
"e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", "e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", 
"e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", "e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", 
"e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", "e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", 
"e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", "e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", 
"e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", "e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", 
"e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", "e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", 
"e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", "e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98", 
"aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", "aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", 
"aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", "aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", 
"aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", "aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", 
"aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", "aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", 
"aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", "aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", 
"aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", "aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", 
"aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", "aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", 
"aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", "aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef", 
"aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef"), DeviceID = c("b8d7b4ab-3d1e-40a1-ba9e-13b7d82d519d", 
"b8136ab5-3e81-4ead-a52b-f23609bc4899", "420dc9bf-c14e-4bcd-9559-e1b491f05182", 
"b8136ab5-3e81-4ead-a52b-f23609bc4899", "ccb94e13-2004-4642-82fb-73fd2cdd979e", 
"b8136ab5-3e81-4ead-a52b-f23609bc4899", "b8d7b4ab-3d1e-40a1-ba9e-13b7d82d519d", 
"b8d7b4ab-3d1e-40a1-ba9e-13b7d82d519d", "ccb94e13-2004-4642-82fb-73fd2cdd979e", 
"b8d7b4ab-3d1e-40a1-ba9e-13b7d82d519d", "420dc9bf-c14e-4bcd-9559-e1b491f05182", 
"b8d7b4ab-3d1e-40a1-ba9e-13b7d82d519d", "420dc9bf-c14e-4bcd-9559-e1b491f05182", 
"b8136ab5-3e81-4ead-a52b-f23609bc4899", "ccb94e13-2004-4642-82fb-73fd2cdd979e", 
"b8136ab5-3e81-4ead-a52b-f23609bc4899", "420dc9bf-c14e-4bcd-9559-e1b491f05182", 
"66a9e7dd-57ee-4c8a-a090-950cae9b02a1", "a8f4bb78-a0f2-476b-9303-2761b06a65fc", 
"66a9e7dd-57ee-4c8a-a090-950cae9b02a1", "66a9e7dd-57ee-4c8a-a090-950cae9b02a1", 
"a8f4bb78-a0f2-476b-9303-2761b06a65fc", "a8f4bb78-a0f2-476b-9303-2761b06a65fc", 
"c293d135-800e-4a62-898d-f0959bf0870d", "66a9e7dd-57ee-4c8a-a090-950cae9b02a1", 
"a8f4bb78-a0f2-476b-9303-2761b06a65fc", "09109879-1061-4325-ae85-9c853dbf7882", 
"09109879-1061-4325-ae85-9c853dbf7882", "c293d135-800e-4a62-898d-f0959bf0870d", 
"66a9e7dd-57ee-4c8a-a090-950cae9b02a1", "a8f4bb78-a0f2-476b-9303-2761b06a65fc", 
"66a9e7dd-57ee-4c8a-a090-950cae9b02a1", "09109879-1061-4325-ae85-9c853dbf7882", 
"66a9e7dd-57ee-4c8a-a090-950cae9b02a1", "6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", 
"6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", "6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", 
"6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", "6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", 
"6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", "6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", 
"6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", "6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", 
"6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", "6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", 
"6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", "6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", 
"6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", "6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", 
"6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", "6caaebb0-775f-4da9-9d34-414e2cb02ef6", 
"41f98340-0724-4dcc-b9bd-1bdd12307f87", "41f98340-0724-4dcc-b9bd-1bdd12307f87", 
"a481ffe1-9bfe-4cac-9da8-553c4da2e224", "41f98340-0724-4dcc-b9bd-1bdd12307f87", 
"a481ffe1-9bfe-4cac-9da8-553c4da2e224", "07d11a53-9b21-4fa1-b055-41f0247c642f", 
"66b65dcb-5416-4bcc-ac9e-2222e2d50a28", "c1ceebbb-24cf-4b1d-8576-8bcb3aaa4534", 
"29277218-9798-406e-b9ee-717184bf6f0e", "41f98340-0724-4dcc-b9bd-1bdd12307f87", 
"41f98340-0724-4dcc-b9bd-1bdd12307f87", "41f98340-0724-4dcc-b9bd-1bdd12307f87", 
"66b65dcb-5416-4bcc-ac9e-2222e2d50a28", "66b65dcb-5416-4bcc-ac9e-2222e2d50a28", 
"29277218-9798-406e-b9ee-717184bf6f0e", "c1ceebbb-24cf-4b1d-8576-8bcb3aaa4534", 
"66b65dcb-5416-4bcc-ac9e-2222e2d50a28", "04ba4776-8afc-4e86-86de-7b85668bf075", 
"a58aa3cc-a231-4a82-8377-56b34306a446", "04ba4776-8afc-4e86-86de-7b85668bf075", 
"7c193822-4ce9-4086-b274-d013e2180ae1", "d2832ac1-f3fd-468a-ace9-efa6a4e25e41", 
"d2832ac1-f3fd-468a-ace9-efa6a4e25e41", "7c193822-4ce9-4086-b274-d013e2180ae1", 
"a58aa3cc-a231-4a82-8377-56b34306a446", "7c193822-4ce9-4086-b274-d013e2180ae1", 
"7c193822-4ce9-4086-b274-d013e2180ae1", "d2832ac1-f3fd-468a-ace9-efa6a4e25e41", 
"7c193822-4ce9-4086-b274-d013e2180ae1", "7c193822-4ce9-4086-b274-d013e2180ae1", 
"4eb8bf81-1f5c-4593-8205-2d0a0d77d0d0", "7c193822-4ce9-4086-b274-d013e2180ae1", 
"7c193822-4ce9-4086-b274-d013e2180ae1", "7c193822-4ce9-4086-b274-d013e2180ae1", 
"58286c18-2df6-461b-8a04-096625f678d2", "58286c18-2df6-461b-8a04-096625f678d2", 
"58286c18-2df6-461b-8a04-096625f678d2", "fc5d9b88-a545-4f69-9c55-7b57103a165c", 
"3007c886-8fde-4b05-8ae5-b4f8df0467a1", "fc5d9b88-a545-4f69-9c55-7b57103a165c", 
"fc5d9b88-a545-4f69-9c55-7b57103a165c", "fc5d9b88-a545-4f69-9c55-7b57103a165c", 
"3007c886-8fde-4b05-8ae5-b4f8df0467a1", "58286c18-2df6-461b-8a04-096625f678d2", 
"fc5d9b88-a545-4f69-9c55-7b57103a165c", "fc5d9b88-a545-4f69-9c55-7b57103a165c", 
"3007c886-8fde-4b05-8ae5-b4f8df0467a1", "58286c18-2df6-461b-8a04-096625f678d2", 
"3007c886-8fde-4b05-8ae5-b4f8df0467a1", "3007c886-8fde-4b05-8ae5-b4f8df0467a1", 
"3007c886-8fde-4b05-8ae5-b4f8df0467a1"), ShowGenre = c("Music", 
"Music", "Sport", "Drama", "Kids", "Documentary", "News", "Movie", 
"Drama", "News", "News", "Kids", "Documentary", "Movie", "Movie", 
"Documentary", "Movie", "Music", "Sport", "Movie", "Movie", "Movie", 
"Drama", "News", "Movie", "Movie", "Documentary", "Movie", "Music", 
"Drama", "News", "News", "Movie", "Drama", "News", "Documentary", 
"Documentary", "Drama", "Music", "Sport", "Sport", "Movie", "Music", 
"Drama", "Sport", "Drama", "Drama", "Kids", "Drama", "Documentary", 
"Sport", "Music", "Music", "Documentary", "Drama", "News", "Music", 
"Music", "Movie", "Documentary", "Documentary", "Documentary", 
"Sport", "Music", "News", "News", "Sport", "Documentary", "Music", 
"Documentary", "News", "Drama", "Drama", "Documentary", "News", 
"Music", "Kids", "Drama", "Documentary", "News", "Drama", "Documentary", 
"Movie", "News", "Kids", "Movie", "Music", "Kids", "Kids", "Movie", 
"Music", "News", "Movie", "Kids", "Music", "Music", "Kids", "Kids", 
"News", "Kids", "Movie", "Documentary"), SessionStart = structure(c(1612132904, 
1612133106, 1612136282, 1612139373, 1612139378, 1612140041, 1612140405, 
1612143192, 1612143292, 1612143854, 1612143976, 1612144065, 1612144220, 
1612144263, 1612144334, 1612144356, 1612146166, 1612146226, 1612146248, 
1612146440, 1612146989, 1612147206, 1612148624, 1612152735, 1612153241, 
1612153475, 1612154929, 1612155104, 1612155562, 1612155992, 1612159668, 
1612159851, 1612160073, 1612165858, 1612168664, 1612169607, 1612169662, 
1612169779, 1612171481, 1612172015, 1612172166, 1612172358, 1612172446, 
1612172505, 1612172544, 1612172601, 1612172607, 1612172969, 1612173898, 
1612175729, 1612177333, 1612178891, 1612180467, 1612180651, 1612181087, 
1612181168, 1612181233, 1612186335, 1612186358, 1612186740, 1612187098, 
1612187181, 1612187519, 1612187704, 1612187730, 1612187890, 1612187936, 
1612188139, 1612188486, 1612188494, 1612188580, 1612192309, 1612192504, 
1612193382, 1612194334, 1612194365, 1612194396, 1612194579, 1612194762, 
1612194984, 1612195094, 1612195096, 1612195252, 1612195837, 1612196401, 
1612199002, 1612200677, 1612200762, 1612200829, 1612201556, 1612201802, 
1612202166, 1612202555, 1612202852, 1612203272, 1612204749, 1612204989, 
1612205005, 1612205067, 1612206077, 1612206260, 1612206263), tzone = "Europe/London", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), SessionEnd = structure(c(1612137925, 1612139792, 
1612140039, 1612141093, 1612139380, 1612143136, 1612140640, 1612143256, 
1612146067, 1612144022, 1612152403, 1612144131, 1612144270, 1612144284, 
1612144337, 1612144652, 1612146227, 1612146238, 1612146439, 1612146493, 
1612152522, 1612148610, 1612149051, 1612153217, 1612153464, 1612154778, 
1612155086, 1612155551, 1612155877, 1612156110, 1612159851, 1612160072, 
1612160227, 1612168654, 1612171480, 1612169607, 1612169740, 1612172007, 
1612172194, 1612172104, 1612172337, 1612172465, 1612172496, 1612172520, 
1612172599, 1612172604, 1612172653, 1612175721, 1612174311, 1612177318, 
1612177340, 1612178923, 1612180650, 1612180839, 1612181167, 1612181232, 
1612181276, 1612186398, 1612186358, 1612186885, 1612187809, 1612187184, 
1612187704, 1612187890, 1612187789, 1612187899, 1612188138, 1612188485, 
1612188498, 1612189623, 1612188597, 1612192404, 1612193479, 1612195723, 
1612194375, 1612194396, 1612194578, 1612194761, 1612194984, 1612195044, 
1612195251, 1612195517, 1612195252, 1612195864, 1612196431, 1612200445, 
1612201368, 1612200786, 1612200896, 1612201633, 1612202122, 1612204649, 
1612205037, 1612203929, 1612203278, 1612204749, 1612205014, 1612205834, 
1612205067, 1612206261, 1612206305, 1612206343), tzone = "Europe/London", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -102L))
```

So in this dataframe, there are 6 unique customer identifiers, each with a varying number of unique devices. Below is a count of unique devices by customer:-

```
* <chr>                                <int>
1 0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87     4
2 12a6dd1e-484c-4c94-a7ab-6443a58b4159     4
3 aeffea0a-fdbf-4c88-8a47-8eaeee4339ef     3
4 e4f0a5ef-f808-4869-9370-c7fcee63ea98     5
5 fb442c22-2595-4245-9f49-a2ea3581ee88     1
6 fc20bfb6-172e-4f55-9467-12ed99579503     6
```

You can imagine that in modern on-demand TV services, someone in a household may be watching a programme on a big screen TV, whilst at the same time, someone is in another room watching a different programme on a tablet/mobile phone/ etc.

Given this context, I want to be able to summarise the following:-

1. How many sessions per customer are active at one time? Using the "SessionStart" timestamp of the first active session and the "SessionEnd" timestamp of the last active session as the defined period.
2. The count of unique devices that are active during this period of sessions
3. The count of unique genres that were being watched across the active sessions

**Desired output**

Here is the first two rows of the dataframe:-

[image]

If these were the only two rows we had to work with, then the desired output would look like this:-

```
CustomerID                                Num_Unique_Devices     Num_Unique_Genre       Genres       
0289d477-427e-4b91-bd4d-8fd579ef2b87               2                    1                 Music

StartTime_FirstSession      EndTime_LastSession
2021-01-31 22:41:44         2021-02-01 00:36:32
```

Can anyone help come up with a solution to get this outcome? It's requiring something that's beyond my expertise at this time so any help is massively appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

We can start by adding a indicator that shows if the current session is
overlapping with the previous section. This can be done like this

```r
(step1 <- df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  group_by(CustomerID) %>% 
  arrange(SessionStart) %>% 
  mutate(
    overlap = SessionStart < lag(SessionEnd)
  )
)
#> # A tibble: 102 x 6
#> # Groups:   CustomerID [6]
#>    CustomerID DeviceID ShowGenre SessionStart        SessionEnd          overlap
#>    <chr>      <chr>    <chr>     <dttm>              <dttm>              <lgl>  
#>  1 0289d477-~ b8d7b4a~ Music     2021-01-31 22:41:44 2021-02-01 00:05:25 NA     
#>  2 0289d477-~ b8136ab~ Music     2021-01-31 22:45:06 2021-02-01 00:36:32 TRUE   
#>  3 0289d477-~ 420dc9b~ Sport     2021-01-31 23:38:02 2021-02-01 00:40:39 TRUE   
#>  4 0289d477-~ b8136ab~ Drama     2021-02-01 00:29:33 2021-02-01 00:58:13 TRUE   
#>  5 0289d477-~ ccb94e1~ Kids      2021-02-01 00:29:38 2021-02-01 00:29:40 TRUE   
#>  6 0289d477-~ b8136ab~ Document~ 2021-02-01 00:40:41 2021-02-01 01:32:16 FALSE  
#>  7 0289d477-~ b8d7b4a~ News      2021-02-01 00:46:45 2021-02-01 00:50:40 TRUE   
#>  8 0289d477-~ b8d7b4a~ Movie     2021-02-01 01:33:12 2021-02-01 01:34:16 FALSE  
#>  9 0289d477-~ ccb94e1~ Drama     2021-02-01 01:34:52 2021-02-01 02:21:07 FALSE  
#> 10 0289d477-~ b8d7b4a~ News      2021-02-01 01:44:14 2021-02-01 01:47:02 TRUE   
#> # ... with 92 more rows
```

The NA’s from the overlap column should just be changed to FALSE. We can do
that with coalesce. The next thing we want is a create a SessionNumber that
increments each time a non-overlapping session starts. One way to do that is
with `cumsum(!overlap)`.

```r
(step2 <- step1 %>% 
  mutate(
    SessionID = cumsum(!coalesce(overlap, FALSE))
  )
)
#> # A tibble: 102 x 7
#> # Groups:   CustomerID [6]
#>    CustomerID DeviceID ShowGenre SessionStart        SessionEnd          overlap
#>    <chr>      <chr>    <chr>     <dttm>              <dttm>              <lgl>  
#>  1 0289d477-~ b8d7b4a~ Music     2021-01-31 22:41:44 2021-02-01 00:05:25 NA     
#>  2 0289d477-~ b8136ab~ Music     2021-01-31 22:45:06 2021-02-01 00:36:32 TRUE   
#>  3 0289d477-~ 420dc9b~ Sport     2021-01-31 23:38:02 2021-02-01 00:40:39 TRUE   
#>  4 0289d477-~ b8136ab~ Drama     2021-02-01 00:29:33 2021-02-01 00:58:13 TRUE   
#>  5 0289d477-~ ccb94e1~ Kids      2021-02-01 00:29:38 2021-02-01 00:29:40 TRUE   
#>  6 0289d477-~ b8136ab~ Document~ 2021-02-01 00:40:41 2021-02-01 01:32:16 FALSE  
#>  7 0289d477-~ b8d7b4a~ News      2021-02-01 00:46:45 2021-02-01 00:50:40 TRUE   
#>  8 0289d477-~ b8d7b4a~ Movie     2021-02-01 01:33:12 2021-02-01 01:34:16 FALSE  
#>  9 0289d477-~ ccb94e1~ Drama     2021-02-01 01:34:52 2021-02-01 02:21:07 FALSE  
#> 10 0289d477-~ b8d7b4a~ News      2021-02-01 01:44:14 2021-02-01 01:47:02 TRUE   
#> # ... with 92 more rows, and 1 more variable: SessionID <int>
```

Finally, we now group_by both CustomerID and SessionID and create the final
dataframe with a summarise.

```r
(step3 <- step2 %>% 
    group_by(CustomerID, SessionID) %>% 
    summarise(
      n_unique_devices = n_distinct(DeviceID),
      n_unique_genres = n_distinct(ShowGenre),
      first_session_start = min(SessionStart),
      last_session_end = max(SessionEnd),
      .groups = "drop"
    )
)
#> # A tibble: 69 x 6
#>    CustomerID     SessionID n_unique_devices n_unique_genres first_session_start
#>  * <chr>              <int>            <int>           <int> <dttm>             
#>  1 0289d477-427e~         1                4               4 2021-01-31 22:41:44
#>  2 0289d477-427e~         2                2               2 2021-02-01 00:40:41
#>  3 0289d477-427e~         3                1               1 2021-02-01 01:33:12
#>  4 0289d477-427e~         4                3               3 2021-02-01 01:34:52
#>  5 0289d477-427e~         5                2               2 2021-02-01 01:50:20
#>  6 0289d477-427e~         6                1               1 2021-02-01 01:52:14
#>  7 0289d477-427e~         7                1               1 2021-02-01 01:52:36
#>  8 0289d477-427e~         8                1               1 2021-02-01 02:22:46
#>  9 12a6dd1e-484c~         1                1               1 2021-02-01 02:23:46
#> 10 12a6dd1e-484c~         2                1               1 2021-02-01 02:24:08
#> # ... with 59 more rows, and 1 more variable: last_session_end <dttm>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you very much for this solution, it works well. I was wondering how to add an additional column which provides a character string of the unique genres watched in step 3?

Comment: You could add  `genres = str_c(unique(ShowGenre), collapse = ",")`  to summarise